# Converting PHP rewriting site to nginx and PHP5-FPM

Tags: php, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm hosting a site for a client on my own virtual servers, which are currently running Apache2. I'm very keen to switch over to `nginx` and `php5-fpm`, but I'm having hassles converting the site's `.htaccess` file properly. (I didn't create the site or the `.htaccess` myself, and to make matters more interesting it also does URL-rewriting.

So the `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search.php(/|$) - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^admin(/|$) - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/author/([^/\.]+)/? index.php?page=blog&filter=author&query=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/date/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/? index.php?page=blog&filter=date&year=$1&month=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/date/([^/\.]+)/? index.php?page=blog&filter=date&year=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/article/([^/\.]+)/? index.php?page=blog&newsId=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=blog&list=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/$ index.php?page=blog [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^download/([^/\.]+) download.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've managed to get the site *nearly* working in `nginx` with the following config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name the-website-com;

  # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
  root /home/web;
  index index.php;

if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}

location /blog {
  rewrite ^/blog/author/([^/\.]+)/? /index.php?page=blog&filter=author&query=$1 last;
  rewrite ^/blog/date/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/? /index.php?page=blog&filter=date&year=$1&month=$2 last;
  rewrite ^/blog/date/([^/\.]+)/? /index.php?page=blog&filter=date&year=$1 last;
  rewrite ^/blog/article/([^/\.]+)/? /index.php?page=blog&newsId=$1 last;
  rewrite ^/blog/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=blog&list=$1 last;
}
location = /blog {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=blog last;
}
location /download {
  rewrite ^/download/([^/\.]+) /download.php?id=$1 last;
}
location / {
  rewrite ([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&sub=$2 last;
  rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include /opt/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

That makes some of the site work. For example, `/contact-us` is fine but for some reason `/our-approach` goes completely wrong and tries to download the PHP file instead of rendering it.

I'm a Rails guy and a bit of a noob when it comes to proxying PHP stuff in `nginx`. Any help very much appreciated!